# How to Extract Image from .DOCX using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Paragraph?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, openxml

I need to extract text and images from a DOCX file in to a text file (save images as graphic files of course).
Using code below how can I get the image and save it with a reference inside the text file?

If I use:

```
List<ImagePart> imgPart = wordProcessingDoc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts.ToList();
```

I can get all the images but sometimes the one image is used in several places. I cannot find out the reference to grab that particular image from the list.
Here is the sample code taken from ([Extract table from DOCX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240933/extract-table-from-docx)):

```
public static string ReadAllTextFromDocx(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileInfo.FullName, false))
    {
        NameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
        xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

        string wordprocessingDocumentText;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            wordprocessingDocumentText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(wordprocessingDocumentText.Length);

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument(nameTable);
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(wordprocessingDocumentText);

        XmlNodeList paragraphNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//w:p", xmlNamespaceManager);
        foreach (XmlNode paragraphNode in paragraphNodes)
        {
            XmlNodeList textNodes = paragraphNode.SelectNodes(".//w:t | .//w:tab | .//w:br | .//w:drawing", xmlNamespaceManager);
            foreach (XmlNode textNode in textNodes)
            {
                switch (textNode.Name)
                {
                    case "w:t":
                        stringBuilder.Append(textNode.InnerText);
                        break;

                    case "w:tab":
                        stringBuilder.Append("\t");
                        break;

                    case "w:br":
                        stringBuilder.Append("\v");
                        break;
                    case "w:drawing":
                        stringBuilder.Append("----------------IMAGE HERE-------------");
                        break;
                }
            }

            stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this post:
[Replace image in word doc using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810138/replace-image-in-word-doc-using-openxml)

```
var imageParts =from graphic in par.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Graphic>()
let graphicData = graphic.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.GraphicData>().FirstOrDefault()
                               let pic = graphicData.ElementAt(0)
                               let nvPicPrt = pic.ElementAt(0).FirstOrDefault()
                               let blip = pic.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip>().FirstOrDefault()
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = blip.GetAttribute("embed", xr).Value,
                                   Filename = nvPicPrt.GetAttribute("name", xpic).Value
                               };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get streams of image from ImagePart.

```
var images = from graphic in paragraph
                .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Graphic>()
            let graphicData = graphic.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.GraphicData>().FirstOrDefault()
            let pic = graphicData.ElementAt(0)
            let nvPicPrt = pic.ElementAt(0).FirstOrDefault()
            let blip = pic.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip>().FirstOrDefault()
            join part in WordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Parts on blip.Embed.Value equals part
                .RelationshipId
            let image = part.OpenXmlPart as ImagePart
            select new
            {
                Id = blip.Embed,
                fileStream = image.GetStream()
            } ;
```